# How to create Horizontal Listview inside vertical listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

I want to create one vertical `ListView` and every row of the list contain `HorizontalListView`.
So in Android how I will implement this lists. So please any one provide me sample code or tutorial.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Now I got one link on which regarding my problem one example [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389071/Create-a-Dynamic-Shelfview-in-Android) is there and It's  working.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use TwoWayView  given:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide

Other ways are:
http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html
and
http://www.airpair.com/android/horizontal-image-galleries-android-studio